# webView.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested is null?

Tags: c#, webview, event-handling, winui-3, webview2

I'm making a browser app in WinUI 3 C#. I have found that when I new tab is requested, a new Edge window opens, because I haven't told the `WebView` what to do when this happens. I have created the method below, which is supposed to be called when the `WebView` gets a new tab request:

```c-sharp
public static void WebView_NewWindowRequested(CoreWebView2 sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e) {
    MainWindow.NewTab(new(e.Uri));
}
```

I then attach this event handler to my `WebView` like this:

```c-sharp
Variables.webViews[index].CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += WebView_NewWindowRequested;
```

However, this throws a `System.NullReferenceException`:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

What is the problem with my code? I have used these other calls to attach other handlers to my `WebView`:

```
Variables.webViews[index].NavigationStarting += WebView_NavigationStarting;
Variables.webViews[index].NavigationCompleted += WebView_NavigationCompleted;
```

And they are virtually the same.

So why is this exception being thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be that `WebView2.CoreWebView2` is null.  It doesn't get initialized until you start navigation, or set `WebView2.Source`.  You must call `WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1418.22)) to get `CoreWebView2` initialized.